# iPad UIModalPresentationPageSheet with navigation controller

Tags: iphone, ipad

I have a `navigationcontroller` and on click of a row I want a sheet:

```
self.modalPresentationStyle=UIModalPresentationPageSheet;
```

that comes up and takes the middle space of the iPad (transparent).

This works fine I want this sheet which is itself a `viewcontroller` to have a table view within it.

When the user clicks on the table row of this sheet, it should navigate and another view should come in as a sliding animation effect, but I am not able to add another `navigationcontroller` to this view.

Is there any way to get this sliding animation effect without navigation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this tutorial http://www.nanaimostudio.com/blog/2010/6/30/modal-form-sheet-navigation-controller.html

The tutorial is not using a table view but in principle it works just the same.